# How to group & sum by multiple keys in an object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to find an efficient way to group and sum data from an object array in javascript. I am open to using the lodash as a library for this, and have researched other similar questions, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Here I would like to create a generic function that takes an array of data, an array of fields to group by and an array of fields to sum.

Take this example object array:

```
const data = [
{
  continent:'North America',
  country:'us',
  state:'ma',
  population: 1567986,
  fee: 24343
},
{
  continent:'North America',
  country:'us',
  state:'tx',
  population: 7567986,
  fee: 119343
},
{
  continent:'North America',
  country:'ca',
  state:'on',
  population: 467986,
  fee: 3343
},
{
  continent:'North America',
  country:'ca',
  state:'qb',
  population: 1268986,
  fee: 54248
},
{
  continent:'Europe',
  country:'ge',
  state:'mc',
  population: 4268986,
  fee: 97333
},
{
  continent:'Europe',
  country:'it',
  state:'fl',
  population: 978353,
  fee: 248
 },
]
```

I want to create a function that looks like:

```
const GroupByFunction = (array, groupbyFields, sumFields) {

}
```

if I called it with say these fields
const result1 = GroupByFuntion(data,['continent'],['population','fee'])

the result would look like this where popSum and popFee are just made up attribute names to hold the summed values:

```
const result1 = [
  {
    contintent:'North America',
    popSum:10872944,
    popfee:201277,
    data: [
    {
      continent:'North America',
      country:'us',
      state:'ma',
      population: 1567986,
      fee: 24343
    },
    {
      continent:'North America',
      country:'us',
      state:'tx',
      population: 7567986,
      fee: 119343
    },
    {
      continent:'North America',
      country:'ca',
      state:'on',
      population: 467986,
      fee: 3343
    },
    {
      continent:'North America',
      country:'ca',
      state:'qb',
      population: 1268986,
      fee: 54248
    },
  ]
},
{
  continent:'Europe',
  popSum: 5247339,
  feeSum:97581,
  data: [
    {
      continent:'Europe',
      country:'ge',
      state:'mc',
      population: 4268986,
      fee: 97333
    },
    {
      continent:'Europe',
      country:'it',
      state:'fl',
      population: 978353,
      fee: 248
    },
  ]
}
]
```

But, I could also pass in multiple group by keys like this:

const result2 = GroupByFuntion(data,['continent','country'],['population','fee'])

and the result would look like this (the popSum and popFee are just junk data placeholders, they would be the summed values from the array):

```
const result2 = [
{
  continent:'North America',
  popSum:10872944,
  popfee:201277,
  country: [
    {
      country:'us',
      popSum: 2423423,
      popFee: 2323,
      data: [
        {
          continent:'North America',
          country:'us',
          state:'ma',
          population: 1567986,
          fee: 24343
        },
        {
          continent:'North America',
          country:'us',
          state:'tx',
          population: 7567986,
          fee: 119343
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      country:'ca',
      popSum: 54443,
      popFee: 34324,
      data: [
        {
          continent:'North America',
          country:'ca',
          state:'on',
          population: 467986,
          fee: 3343
        },
        {
          continent:'North America',
          country:'ca',
          state:'qb',
          population: 1268986,
          fee: 54248
        }, 
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  continent:'Europe',
  popSum: 3432423,
  popFee: 3432,
  country: [
    {
      country: 'gb',
      popSum: 32432,
      popFee: 564,
      data: [
        {
          continent:'Europe',
          country:'ge',
          state:'mc',
          population: 4268986,
          fee: 97333
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      country: 'it',
      popSum: 89332,
      popFee: 8932,
      data: [
        {
          continent:'Europe',
          country:'ge',
          state:'mc',
          population: 4268986,
          fee: 97333
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
},
]
```

Is this possible using the _groupBy and _sumBy functions in lodash, or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to achieve what you want :

```js
const data = [
    {
        continent:'North America',
        country:'us',
        state:'ma',
        population: 1567986,
        fee: 24343
    },
    {
        continent:'North America',
        country:'us',
        state:'tx',
        population: 7567986,
        fee: 119343
    },
    {
        continent:'North America',
        country:'ca',
        state:'on',
        population: 467986,
        fee: 3343
    },
    {
        continent:'North America',
        country:'ca',
        state:'qb',
        population: 1268986,
        fee: 54248
    },
    {
        continent:'Europe',
        country:'ge',
        state:'mc',
        population: 4268986,
        fee: 97333
    },
    {
        continent:'Europe',
        country:'it',
        state:'fl',
        population: 978353,
        fee: 248
    },
]


const groupBy = (rawArray, groupbyFields, sumFields) => {
    const field = groupbyFields[0]
    const fieldValues = new Set()

    rawArray.forEach(e => fieldValues.add(e[field]))

    const array = []

    for (const fieldValue of fieldValues.values()) {
        let data = rawArray.filter(e => e[field] === fieldValue)

        if (groupbyFields.length > 1) {
            data = groupBy(data, groupbyFields.slice(1), sumFields)
        }

        const obj = { data }

        sumFields.forEach(sumField => {
            const sumFieldName = `${ sumField }Sum`
            obj[sumFieldName] = data.map(e => e[sumField] ?? e[sumFieldName] ?? 0).reduce((g, c) => g + c, 0)
        })

        obj[field] = fieldValue
        array.push(obj)
    }

    return array
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupBy(data, [ 'continent', 'country' ],[ 'population', 'fee' ]), null, '  '))
```

Comment: not quite, I put in just "continent" as the group by fielld and it comes back as undefined in output, also, it didn't group the results by continent. The grouping by "continent' and 'country; also didn't have expected /matching output to what I was hoping for.

Comment: I don’t really understand what is your problem
It seems to work just fine for me with the dataset your provided (with "contintent" replaced by "continent")

Comment: you're right, it was my own stupid typo...works great, thx!